# what we consider the significance if the F calculated value equal to F tabulated?

Tags: statistical-significance, f-test

if for example, we define the significant level at P<0.05 and the F calculated was equal to F tabulated. now the question is does we consider it significant or not?
I did not find a refrence answer

Answer (score 0):

Then your P-value will exactly equal 0.05, and is thus borderline significant on the 5% significance level. See also [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79855/is-p-5-0-significant?rq=1). Please do not put too much into the "canonical" 5% significance level.