# Term for baseline with randomly distributed classes over same data points

Tags: small-sample, spurious-correlation

I have a dataset with few (20,000) data points and many (100) features ranging from 0 to 1. The dataset is divided into two classes with even distribution. I'm doing a classification task on this and want to compare that to a reasonable baseline.

One option would be to take a random guessing baseline where we consider the same classes but without features. That would give an accuracy of 0.5, because the classes are evenly distributed.

As the feature-data point ratio increases, [spurious correlations](http://www.tylervigen.com/spurious-correlations) make it easier to classify the data points. I therefore take another baseline, where I use the same data but randomly distribute the classes over the data points. Then I build the same classifier on that data (B), and compare it to the classifier built on the actual data (A). The difference between (A) and (B) tells me how I improve compared to 'seeing patterns in randomness'; the difference between (B) and the random guessing baseline tells me how easy it is to find spurious correlations in the dataset.

Is there a name for a baseline like (B) described here?

Comment: You are asking about using *permutation test*, is this the term you're looking for?

Comment: @Tim thank you! That is exactly what I'm looking for. I needed to know the name to discuss and reference it in my report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is a **permutation test**. Permutation tests are one of the [resampling methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_(statistics)) used in statistics. If you want to read more on such methods, you can check the introductory book *Introduction to Statistics Through Resampling Methods and R* by Phillip I. Good. You can also find an example [in this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/295246/how-to-apply-bootstrapping-in-this-case/295764#295764).